# Relative velocity from space-time diagram

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, relativity, relative-motion

Consider two frames of reference, with velocities V1 and V2 relative to an initial ground frame.  I have made the space-time diagrams for the three frames (Time represented on Y-axis).
[image: desc]

As far as I know, the relative velocity between frame-1 and frame-2 (relative velocity is represented in green) is the projection of net velocity of frame-2 (i.e., t2 axis) on space-1 (x1) axis or Vise-Versa.

So,
  Considering $c = 1$,
$=> V21 = \sin(\beta-\alpha)$
$=> V21 = (\sin\beta \cos\alpha  - \cos\alpha \sin\beta)$

We can simply calculate values of sines and cosines.
$\sin\alpha = V1/1 = V1$
$\sin\beta = V2/1 = V2$

$=> V21 = ( V2\sqrt{(1-V1^2)} - V1\sqrt{(1-V2^2)})$

While we know the correct formula,
$V21 = (V2-V1)/(1-V1V2)$

What is wrong with this approach to find relative velocities?

It worked correctly for calculating the space-time transformation relations between two frames.

Sorry for the bad diagram.

Comment: 1.  Why do you think the spatial axes are oriented as you've drawn them (i.e. orthogonal to the time axis)? 2. Where do $\sin \alpha = V_1$ etc. come from? 3.Why do you think $V_{12}$ is the projection of $V_2$ in this frame onto the $x_1$ axis? Keep in mind that when you superpose spacetime diagrams, the "scales" of the axes will be different in general.

Comment: 1. That is what space-time diagrams represent, right? I mean, they may not be really perpendicular, but we can geometrically represent it because the Pythagorean addition of time-velocity and space-velocity is speed of light. 2. By simple geometry ??  3. The total velocity of frame-2 (or any other frame) in space-time is c. But, frame-1 can see frame-2 moving only in frame-1's space. So, frame -2 can be seen with 'speed of light' projected onto space of frame-1.  I couldn't understand what you are saying about that scales of axes.    Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thank You.

Comment: This method perfectly worked and agreed with the actual formulae when I superposed only two spacetime diagrams. I found out the time-dilation and length-contraction and also relation between the space-time values of an event in two different frames. So why isn't it gonna work here?

Comment: Consider only frame-0 and frame-1.  Place a rod of length L in space axis of frame-0. How is frame-1 gonna view it? The rod is visible to frame-1 only in frame-1's space, right? Thus, projection of L (which is in X0) upon X1 is   L*cos(alpha) = L*sqrt(1-(V/c)^2).......Length Contraction.

Comment: $
\sin \left( \beta -\alpha \right) =\sin \left( \beta \right)  \cos \left( \alpha \right) -\cos \left( \beta \right) \sin\left( \alpha\right) $

Comment: BTW, member robphy has a nice way of drawing spacetime diagrams on rotated graph paper, eg https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/325582/123208

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your spacetime diagram is wrong: you're using Euclidean geometry, when you should be using Minkowski. The actual diagram, if you'll forgive the low quality picture, looks something like this:

[image]

where I've drawn the $t^2 - x^2 = \pm 1$ hyperbolae, and the angles obey $\tan \alpha = v_1$ and $\tan \beta = v_2$. Note that that unit vectors have unit length with respect to the Minkowski metric but not with respect to the Euclidean metric: they lie on a hyperbola, not on a circle.

If you want to see how things look from frame 1, you have to move everything out along the hyperbolae:

[image]

where now $\delta$ is the unknown angle we want to find. To find it geometrically, however, we need to do some algebra first, because the geometry is hyperbolic, and it doesn't correspond to what happens when we draw on paper. And the key fact we need is that if given a velocity $v$ we define the *rapidity* $\eta$ by $v = \tanh \eta$, such that $\eta$ goes from zero to infinity as $v$ goes from zero to one, then when doing Lorentz transformations, rapidities simply add. This is still geometric, in a sense, because rapidity is a parameter along the hyperbolae, though it's not the usual arclength.

From this, the velocity addition formula is straightforward if we know our hyperbolic identities: since rapidities simply add and subtract, we have that $\eta_{21} = \eta_2-\eta_1$, and

$$v_{21} = \tanh(\eta_2 - \eta_1) = \frac{\tanh{\eta_2} - \tanh{\eta_1}}{1 - \tanh{\eta_2}\tanh{\eta_1}} = \frac{v_2 - v_1}{1 - v_1 v_2}.$$