# How can a proton travel the milky-way in 296 seconds?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, lorentz-symmetry

In the Introductory Special Relativity book, by W. G. V. Rosser, the author presented an example about Lorentz Length contraction. In this example, a proton is crossing the milky-way galaxy and he is calculating the time required for the proton to cross the galaxy from two inertial reference frames. From the proton's reference frame, it is considered stationary at the origin and the galaxy is moving towards the it. In the second reference frame, the proton is moving while the galaxy is considered stationary. According to the author's calculations, the time required for the proton to cross the galaxy is 296 s in the former frame while $3.15×10^{12}$ s in the latter one. How can we explain this? I understand how the author did the calculations, but I am trying to visualize time dilation and Lorentz contraction and I am encountering difficulties in this!

Comment: I understand your difficulty visualizing time dilation. But what is your difficulty visualizing a length-contracted galaxy? Is it really that you can’t visualize it, or can’t believe that it happens?

Comment: I know that both are treated as independent phenomena. So I guess if I am not understanding time dilation, that means I am not understanding length contraction! Am I correct?

Comment: I just cannot accept the idea how can a proton travel the galaxy in 296 seconds! How can this happen?

Comment: I wouldn't like to be hit by too many protons with that much KE. ;)

Comment: In the proton’s frame, the galaxy is extremely squished. Instead of being 50,000 light-years across, it is 296 light-seconds across.

Comment: I can't figure out what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

These spacetime diagrams for the muon problem from an [earlier post of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/325359/if-two-observer-dont-agree-about-distance-traveled-and-the-times-it-takes-why) might help answer your question by "visualizing" proper time and length contraction.

In the first diagram, I've drawn it using "rotated graph paper" so that it's easier to visualize the ticks along worldlines and along lines of simultaneity. The diamond-edges represent the light-rays of a light-clock,
and Lorentz transformations preserve the directions of the edges and the area.

For simplicity, suppose the particle travels at (4/5)c
and the lab frame says it takes the particle 10 seconds to travel 8 light-seconds. The particle has aged on 6 second along the trip. From the diagram, the time-dilation factor is $\gamma=(10/6)=(5/3)$. 
(This can be checked using the formula, $\gamma=(1-v^2)^{-1/2}$.)

As a Minkowski right-triangle, the legs are time and spatial displacements (10 and 8) in the lab frame, and the hypotenuse is the time-displacement in the particle-frame.

To see what the particle measures, we need to construct the spatial displacement according to the particle between the worldlines of the peak and ground. This segment OX is Minkowski-perpendicular to the muon worldline. Its size is $v\Delta \tau=(4/5)6=4.8$.

Interpreted as a length contraction problem, think of an 8 light-sec ruler (8 light-sec in the lab frame)  moving with velocity (-v) in the particle frame. The particle observes that length to be $8/\gamma=8/(5/3)=4.8$.

[image: RRGP-muonsSimple-robphy]

For more realistic values, $v=0.999c$ (so, $\gamma \approx 22.366$ with $\Delta \tau=2.2\mu s$, we have these values (although it's not drawn to scale here).
In this diagram, I'm using the hyperbolic-trigonometric functions to work with Minkowski-right-triangles, where $(v/c)=\tanh\theta$ and $\theta$ is the Minkowski-angle [called "rapidity"] between the timelike worldlines.
So, $\gamma=\cosh\theta=(1-\tanh^2\theta)^{-1/2}=\cosh({\rm arctanh}(v))$.
Thus, $\cosh({\rm arctanh}(.999))\approx 22.366$
[image: SpacetimeTrig-muons-robphy]

For your problem, using what you have given (since I don't have access to that passage in Rosser),
$\gamma=\cosh\theta=\frac{3.15\times 10^{12}}{296}\approx 1.06^{10}$.
From WolframAlpha, the velocity is $v=\tanh({\rm arccosh}(\frac{3.15\times 10^{12}}{296}))=0.99999999999999999999558498362308...$ 
[$1-v=4.41\times 10^{-21}$].

The apparent length of the galaxy according to the proton
is $L_{apparent}=v\Delta \tau=v(296 \rm sec)\approx 296(1-4.41\times 10^{-21})\mbox{light-seconds}$.

By length contraction, the above is related to 
the rest length $L$ of the galaxy by
$L_{apparent}=\frac{L}{\gamma}$.

So,
$L=\gamma L_{apparent}=\cosh\theta (\tanh\theta\Delta \tau)=\sinh\theta\Delta\tau=3.15\times 10^{12}$ light-seconds, as expected.
Indeed, if you ask WolframAlpha
"296*sinh(arccosh(3.15e12/296))", you get 3.15e12. (One can derive it from trigonometry.)

In light-years, $$(3.15\times 10^{12} \mbox{light-sec})(\frac{1 \mbox{yr}}{\pi \times 10^7\rm{sec}}) \approx 10^5\mbox{light-year}.$$

Answer (score -1):

The effect is entirely symmetrical. If there was a second proton moving at the same speed as the first a distance X behind it, where X was the diameter of the Milky Way, we would see the second proton pass us 296 seconds after the first. Since we are justified in taking the view that we are travelling and the protons are stationary, we can say that we crossed the Milky-way-sized gap between the two protons in 296 seconds. On the other hand, if the protons were wearing synchronised watches (in their frame) the second proton would say that he saw us go past 50,000 years after the first one did.

Comment: Yes, the effect is symmetrical. But your answer is incredibly confusing. If the second proton is moving X behind it *in our frame*, we will see it cross 3.15×10$^{12}$  s after the first one, because the second proton would enter the Milky Way when the first one left it.

Answer (score -2):

You are basically asking about Special Relativity time dilation and length contraction.

Time dilation is the difference in the elapsed time measured by two clocks due to them having a velocity relative to each other.

> > After compensating for varying signal delays due to the changing distance between an observer and a moving clock (i.e. Doppler effect), the observer will measure the moving clock as ticking slower than a clock that is at rest in the observer's own reference frame.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation

Length contraction is the phenomenon that a moving object's length is measured to be shorter then it's proper length, which is the length measured in the object's rest frame.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction

Now there are two ways to look at it in your case:

1. time dilation

The proton is traveling at relativistic speeds, thus if you would travel with the proton and would have a clock, you would see that your clock ticks faster relative to a clock that is at rest at the galaxy. Now if you are a stationary observer in the galaxy, and there is a moving clock moving with the proton, you will see this moving clock tick slower then your own clock stationary in the galaxy. In this case if you are stationary in the galaxy, you will see 296 seconds to elapse on the moving clock (moving with the proton), and you will see 50000 years elapse on your own clock (stationary in the galaxy). This difference in the elapsed time on the clocks is caused due to time dilation caused by the relativistic speed of the proton.

2. length contraction

The proton is a composite particle, and does have rest mass, thus, it does have a inertial reference frame. Thus it does make sense to say "what would the galaxy look like if we would be in the proton's rest frame."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction

[image]

[image]

As you can see from the picture, the galaxy would look squished in the direction of travel, thus, it would look like it is 296 light seconds long diagonally (in the direction of travel), and that's what it would look like if you would travel with the proton.

Comment: Point 1 is the opposite of the truth; a proton (like any other observer) sees its own clock tick *faster* than any other clock, not slower.

Comment: @WillO this is why SR time dilation is called symmetrically relative. I will edit my answer so that the time elapsed is measured from the galaxy's frame.

Comment: @Некто are you talking about the comments? I edited my question based on the comments.

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei sorry just seeing this. Deleted my comment

Comment: After your edit, this is still all wrong. Obviously all observers must agree about how many times the proton's clock ticks. Everyone must agree that the proton's clock ticks off exactly 267 seconds over the course of its journey. So the bit that says "(The proton's) clock would show 50000 years elapse" is your first mistake.

Comment: @WillO OK I edited, please see it is OK.

Comment: After your second edit the part on time dilation seems correct, but I'm not sure it adds anything to what the OP has told us he already knows.