# How to understand the behaviour of a muon in two different reference frames

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, spacetime, reference-frames, speed-of-light

How should I visualize the disturbing behavior of accelerated muons At the 14 metre diameter AGS synchrotron facility in Brookhaven? At this facility muons have been accelerated to 99.94% of the speed of light. With a 2.2 micro second half life, at this speed they should only be able to manage around 15 laps on average before they expire.

But due to time dilation effects, they appear to survive longer and a stationary observer standing beside the machine sees them go past 400 times. From the muon’s perspective it must also do 400 laps. But this causes a problem because the muon appears to have different half lives in the two different reference frames, yet travels the same number of laps.

The answer (at least according to Brian Cox in why does E=mc^2 ~page 54) is that from the muon’s perspective the circumference of the ring is reduced because the length of the ring must shrink by exactly the same amount that the muon’s lifetime increases. All well and good

BUT My problem is trying to adjust my own mental picture to the reality of what is going on when the muon flight path has different diameters in different time frames. The stationary ring magnets in the 14m diameter synchrotron appear to have an influence on the muons in their 2cm diameter circuit (presumably in the centre of the ring? How can I visualize what is going on?

Comment: You seem to have answered your question. From the _frame of the muon_, the circumference of the ring is _length contracted_. The muon travels the same number of laps (where each lap is a much large distance according to an outside observer). Trying to make a mental picture of what's happening using classical thinking wont help.

Comment: If, for simplicity,  you allow the curved trajectory to be unwound, you might find my answer helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/325582/148184 to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/325359/if-two-observer-dont-agree-about-distance-traveled-and-the-times-it-takes-why .

Comment: Yes from the muons frame of reference the diameter is length contracted I understand that from an intellectual point of view.  It just doesn't seem to make any sense that the frame of reference of the muon bears no relation to the frame of reference of the synchrotron and the magnets that are driving the muon. You are probably right that making a mental picture using classical thinking is not helpful, but I need some sort of mental relativistic picture if I am ever to properly understand the effect.