# Asymmetry in infamous Muon example

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

The immediate example usually given in relativity courses after teaching relativistic time dilation is concerned with the detection of muon flux on earth's atmosphere. The problem is that the average lifetime they have when studied at rest is $t=2\times10^{-6}$ seconds, and they are created at a distance of $50$ km with speed $0.99c$. Thus classically muons will never reach the surface of the earth. But using time dilation we get that the time passed on earth is $\gamma t$ and not $t$. However, muon can say the same thing in reverse, that is time on its clock is $t$, and earth is moving thus earth's clock reads $t/\gamma$. But this is not what the clocks on earth read, according to earth's frame. Where does error creep in? I know this can be easily solved using LTs, but if the time dilation method gives the right result in the earth frame then it should also give in muon's frame by symmetry unless my understanding is flawed, hence this question.

Comment: Possibly useful: my analysis of the muon experiment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/325582/148184 ... analyzed in the earth frame and in the muon frame.

Comment: Don't forget to length contract the distance that the muon sees in it's rest frame which is only ~7km.

Comment: @Triatticus That seemed irrelevant to the question, even more so when both earth and muon are moving WRT "fixed stars", thus I didn't mention it. Also, the question is not about making sense of the result of $t/\gamma$, but using the same reasoning for earth's case to get the correct answer.

Comment: What I mean is you have to include that in your "asymmetry," it's part of the problem that in Earth's frame the muon lasts longer and can cover that distance. But in the muons frame it doesn't have to cover that same distance due to length contraction. It sees a very squashed earth and thin atmosphere incoming at $.99c$

Comment: @Triatticus I am not sure I follow, this example does not require anything other than time dilation, sure the distance according to muon is contracted in such a manner that the time earth reaches it is precise $t$, but that's not the point. The point is that given some time has passed according to a muon (whatever it may be), by using time dilation, what will be time passed on earth?

Comment: This question is based on a false premise. The Earth clocks **are** time dilated in the muon’s frame. The asymmetry mentioned simply doesn’t exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation is inherently asymmetric because you are looking at 3 clocks: the muon's internal clock, and two Earth based clocks (one at the top of the atmosphere, and one on the ground). From the statement of your problem it appears that the muon clock and Earth atmosphere clock are set to 0 when the muon passes the top of atmosphere clock. The difficulty comes in ascertaining what the Earth ground clock reads at that moment, because the very phrase "at that moment" is ambiguous: simultaneity is relative. In the Earth based reference frame both Earth clocks are synchronized and so both show 0 at the same time, and both will show $T$ when the muon reaches the ground. In the muon based reference frame the Earth clocks are *not* showing the same time: the ground based one is ahead of the atmosphere based one and shows $T - \frac{T}{\gamma}$ when the atmosphere one shows 0. The Earth clocks are both time dilated (relative to the muon's frame) and so in the muon's frame the atmosphere clock reads $\frac{T}{\gamma}$ and the ground one reads $T$ when the ground reaches the muon, both having ticked for $\frac{T}{\gamma}$ cycles.

The fundamental takeaway is that the Lorentz transformation involves both time *and* space, and so spatially separated clocks show the same values at the same time only in the reference frame where they are both at rest.

Answer (score 1):

There is no asymmetry. Time dilation applies symmetrically, but in a very specific way that you need to understand.

Specifically, the time dilation formula applies only when a single clock which is stationary in one frame is directly compared with *two spatially separated clocks* which are stationary in another frame.

Imagine then you have the muon frame and the Earth frame moving relative to each other at such a speed that the time dilation factor is sixty, say. In that case, if a single clock in the muon frame spends a second coasting between two clocks in the Earth frame, the difference between the readings on the first clock it passes and on the second will be one minute. So the single muon clock will seem time dilated compared with the two Earth clocks. Conversely, if you are holding one of the Earth clocks, and you are passed by two clocks in the muon frame, one a second after the other according to your clock, the reading on the second clock will be a minute ahead of the first- ie your clock will seem time dilated compared to the two moving clocks.